# Read json with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multilingual

I want to keep my site multilingual. For this reason I have following example json-file for labels etc.:

**fruits.json:**

```
{
    "apple" : {
        "en" : "apple",
        "de" : "apfel"
    },
    "banana" : {
        "en" : "banana",
        "de" : "banane"
    },
    "cherry" : {
        "en" : "cherry",
        "de" : "kirsche"
    }
}
```

The page controller creates an array from it:

**PHP:**

```
$lang = json_decode(file_get_contents("fruits.json"), true);
```

At the moment I access the needed labels in page view with following code:

```
$lang['apple']['de'];
```

---

Is there an easier way to achieve the final result? It would be nice to remove the language index from the page view, so last code would look like "$lang['apple']".

But the general question: Is this a good way for a multilingual site? Or should I structure the files in a different way?

Comment: pls show what its showing and what you want it to show and what type of output function your using are you using var_dump? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to skip json, as the keys might change. Makes more sense to simply keep an array in the master language, and map all other languages to it. This can be done simply as a master language file with a message/word on each line, and then translated files in each language that map directly to the line numbers. It is easier to manage this way too. To make a translation, simply copy the master file, and change the words into the new language line by line, which can be done by translators who are not programmers, and might be unfamiliar with JSON etc...

The best way I have seen, is to use `pot` (person oriented templates) to produce `po` (person oriented) files, which then get compiled to `mo` files (machine oriented) for better performance. There are lots of web based and desktop tools for working with pot/po/mo files. I have used them in wordpress, using plugins to manage the translations with great success.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you're in half-good approach. It's ok to store i18n in a json-alike file. But I think it's better if you provide separate files for each language. So you'd have a separate file for English and Deutsch json translations. Therefore you'd have:

```
{
    "apple" : "apfel",
    "banana" : "banane",
    "cherry" : "kirsche"
}
```

for Deutsch. It's easier to maintain such files if you have many languages, because you don't edit 1 gigantic file. You add one single file instead.

you can have a i18n directory where you'd store i18n files:

```
i18n/
    en.json
    de.json
```

You'd create a class that reads all files with .json extensions and provide one i18n function with 2 arguments:

```
fun translate(lang, key)
{
    // access your i18n data here
}
```

This function would be directly accessed from View layer (MVC).

Another approach is to store i18n in a database, if you want it do be editable easily. It depends on you business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "de" : {
    "apple" : "apfel",
    "banana" : "banane",
    "cherry" : kirsche
  }
}
```

I think using language as a top level dimension solves it.
Then once you decode the json file you just need to get the array of that language and it will have all the contents you need.

```
$lang_all = json_decode(file_get_contents("fruits.json"), true);
$lang=$lang_all['de'];
```

Then you can access using $lang['apple'].

Comment: This worked for me. I suggest to create a function to inform of non found elements.   

if ( array_key_exists('apple', $lang) ) {
   echo  $lang['apple'];
  } else {
   echo  'not present';
  }

Answer (score 0):

After you read the JSON into `$lang`, you can make a new array containing the current language:

```
$words = array_map(function($word) use ($curlang) { return $word[$curlang]; }, $lang);
```

Then you can access `$words['apple']`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not really a human readable format.

As previously said, i also advise to use separate files for each language, and more, I advise you to use separate folder by lang and use a file by theme/plugin/library/feature (but your application is plugin sized).

A lot of frameworks can help you to use a good architecture and some tools (already coded).

You can also see PO/MO files, i18n and gettext().